# How to set permissions to a Google VM for Cloud Repositories without shutting down the VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-source-repositories

I want to give a GCP VM access to Cloud Source Repository but without having to shutdown the VM because I have some processes running. Is this possible or I need to wait until the processes are done, turn off the VM and grant the permissions needed? How can I achieve this? Sorry for the naive question, I'm still learning how to use well GCP products :(.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to **IAM & Admin > IAM** and look for the service account used by your Compute Engine instance. If you're using the default service account, this is the format:

```
PROJECTNUMBER-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com
```

Afterwards, click "Edit Member" then select a role and look for "Source". You should be able to see these following roles:

- Source Repository Administrator
- Source Repository Writer
- Source Repository Role

Select which [role](https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/configure-access-control#roles_and_permissions_matrix) is best for your use case then hit save.

Comment: Hi @Donnald C. Thank you for your answer. I did as you said and when trying to do `git clone` I'm getting this error `Permission denied (publickey)`. If I go to the VM details, it still shows Cloud Source Repository disabled :(

Comment: Try this command: `gcloud source repos clone REPONAME --project=PROJECTID`. Replace the uppercase with your credentials

Comment: Did it and got this error: `PERMISSION_DENIED: Request had insufficient authentication scopes. If you are in a compute engine VM, it is likely that the specified scopes during VM creation are not enough to run this command. See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam for more information of access scopes.
See https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes for how to update access scopes of the VM.`

Comment: Following this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#gcloud_1), it says _**To change an instance's service account and access scopes, the instance must be temporarily stopped.**_. So I guess I can't grant the instance access to the repository until its done with the current scripts :(.

Comment: I see. It turns out that your access scope is configured for each API instead of having full access to all Cloud APIs. In that case you're right.